# How to enable user supplied vertex id in OrientDb?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I am trying to understand if it is possible to have user supplied vertex ids?

I found this, but I am inexperienced in Java so I can't really understand this for sure. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/master/driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/OrientGraph.java#L177

For JanusGraph there is `graph.set-vertex-id=true`, but is there similar for OrientDb? Or with Tinkergraph `gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=ANY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDb **do not** support user supplied vertex id, as you can tell it from the code:
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/master/driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/OrientGraph.java#L182

```
@Override
public Vertex addVertex(Object... keyValues) {
    ...
        if (ElementHelper.getIdValue(keyValues).isPresent()) throw Vertex.Exceptions.userSuppliedIdsNotSupported();
```

You can also tell it from the code of ODBFeatures, the implement of interface `supportsUserSuppliedIds`:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/blob/master/driver/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/orientdb/ODBFeatures.java

Comment: Thank you, I guess all dbs who implement gremlin tinkerpop have to implement this interface, so I know where to check for this in the future! 
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/d12adfbf083f575fa48860daa37bfbd0e6095369/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/tinkerpop/JanusGraphFeatures.java